# como seleccionar segun según atributo selector en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una duda sobre como puedo seleccionar todos los **< select >** de un documento pero solo los que **no** sean select multiples **< select multiple=''>** como puedo realizar esta validacion en jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilizando el selector de negación (pseudoclase :not) junto con su atributo (multiple en este caso):

```
$('select:not([multiple])')
```

Comment: Gracias amigo muy gentil ;)